# Different uses of ServiceLocatorInterface in ZF2 Application

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have 2 factories.

The first is a Controller Factory:

```
    <?php
    namespace Blog\Factory;

    use Blog\Controller\ListController;
    use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
    use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

    class ListControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
    {
        public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
        {
            $realServiceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();        
            $postService = $realServiceLocator->get('Blog\Service\PostServiceInterface');
            return new ListController($postService);
        }
    }
```

The second is a Post ServiceFactory:

```
    <?php
    namespace Blog\Factory;

    use Blog\Service\PostService;
    use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
    use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

    class PostServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
    {
         /**
          * Create service
          *
          * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
          * @return mixed
          */
         public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
         {
             return new PostService(
                 $serviceLocator->get('Blog\Mapper\PostMapperInterface')
             );
         }
    }
```

Here is my module config:

```
    <?php
    return array(
        'service_manager' => array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Blog\Service\PostServiceInterface' => 'Blog\Factory\PostServiceFactory'
            )
        ),
        'controllers' => array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Blog\Controller\List' => 'Blog\Factory\ListControllerFactory'
            )
        ),
        'router' => array(
            // Open configuration for all possible routes
            'routes' => array(
                // Define a new route called "post"
                'post' => array(
                    // Define the routes type to be "Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal", which is basically just a string
                    'type' => 'literal',
                    // Configure the route itself
                    'options' => array(
                        // Listen to "/blog" as uri
                        'route'    => '/blog',
                        // Define default controller and action to be called when this route is matched
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Blog\Controller\List',
                            'action'     => 'index',
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        'view_manager' => array(
            'template_path_stack' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/../view',
            ),
        )
    );
```

In the controller factory, I have to call `getServiceLocator` against the `ServiceLocatorInterface`, followed by the `get` call. however in the post service factory i just call `get`. I did a dump and it looks like both are the `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager` classes. When I tried performing the `getServiceLocator` call against the post service factory service locator it errored no method found.

Im not quite understanding whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

Controller factories are called in a different way than casual service factories. The `ServiceLocator` passed to `createService` is actually not the `ServiceManager` you are looking for but an instance of `ControllerManager`.

If you try this:

```
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
{
    $realServiceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
    $postService = $realServiceLocator->get('Blog\Service\PostServiceInterface');

    var_dump(get_class($serviceLocator));

    return new ListController(postService );
}
```

you'll get the output:

```
string(37) "Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager"
```

while the same dump in your `PostServiceFactory` will give you:

```
string(34) "Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager"
```

From the Zend 2 documentation:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/services-and-servicemanager.html#writing-a-factory-class

> When using a Factory-Class that will be called from the `ControllerManager` it will actually inject itself as the `$serviceLocator`. However, we need the real `ServiceManager` to get to our Service-Classes. This is why we call the function `getServiceLocator()` who will give us the real `ServiceManager`.